# Mongo with Spring Data - Use Distinct and Orderby in the same query

Tags: spring, mongodb, jquery-mobile, spring-data-mongodb

I am working on some dataset whose json format for one object is given below.

```
{
  _id: ............,
   code : G12220,
   type : etf,
   volume : 13,
   modified_time:..................
   .
   .
   .
}
```

This dataset gets updated very frequently (every 1 minute) and there are few thousands unique codes. I want to write a query to fetch the set of documents for each of the most latest distinct "codes" available. Eg: If there are two documents each having same code the result should be the most latest. I am using Spring Data.

I started writing my query and the given below is a sample.

```
@Query("{type : ?0}......")
public List<ProductEntities> getLatestProductsSet(String type);
```

I am not very sure how to write a complex query on this. Would be grateful if you can help me.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the following mongo query to achieve this.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": { 
            "_id": { 
                "code": "$code", 
                "modifiedTime": "$modified_time" 
            },
            "docs": { 
                "$push": "$$ROOT" 
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": { 
            "_id.modifiedTime": -1 
        }
    },
    {
        "$limit": 1
    }
]);
```

Following are the links which will help you understand the above query.

```
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/
```

Spring part follows.

```
http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-aggregation-grouping-example/
```

Let me know, if this helps.